# Is there an easy way to lock some columns in pandas dataframe from being manipulated?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a function to every column except a couple that needs to remain unchanged.
The way I am doing it right now:

1. Assign xxx columns to a variable
2. Drop xxx columns from df
3. Do some operation on df
4. Merge variable to df

Example:

```
cobId = combined.Id
cobSale = combined.SalePrice
combined = combined.drop(['Id', 'SalePrice'], axis = 1)
combined=(combined-combined.mean())/combined.std()
combined['Id'] = cobId
combined['SalePrice'] = cobSale
```

**How to imporve here?**

Comment: please tell me if my solution works

Comment: @ansev It works great, thanks body. Only personal preference that I don't like using .sub and .div - I like just using - and /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
cols = combined.columns.difference(['Id','SalePrice'])
combined[cols] = combined[cols].sub(combined[cols].mean()).div(combined[cols].std())
print(combined)
```

---

**Here is an example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2],'col2':[3,4]})
print(df)
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

---

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['col1'])
df[cols] = df[cols].sub(df[cols].mean()).div(df[cols].std())

print(df)
```

---

We can also use [`DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df2=df.drop(axis=1,labels='col1')
#df2=df[df.columns.difference(['col1'])]
df2 = df2.sub(df2.mean()).div(df2.std())
df.update(df2)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   col1      col2
0     1 -0.707107
1     2  0.707107
```